# Laravel (blade) @lang em componentes do Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Recentemente comecei a utilizar VueJs com Laravel e um dos primeiros problemas que dei de cara foi como utilizar as traduções do Laravel (da pasta `resource/lang` ) nos Componentes do Vue pois no Blade é simplesmente utilizar @lang, ou @choice por exemplo.

E como minha primeira solução eu passei as traduções como variáveis através do Blade para o componente, mas o que acontece é que dentro de outro componente eu chamo outro componente e não queria ficar passando as traduções através de variáveis pois polui muito.

E estava pensando em utilizar o VueResource nos componentes para mandar uma requisição para a API e da API retornar um array inteiro com as traduções que preciso.

A minha pergunta é: isso é viável de se fazer? E caso não, o que devo fazer.

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse repositório (https://github.com/jcc/blog), aqui tem um exemplo de multi lang com vue e laravel.